Children's book featuring a girl in a blue dress riding a broom
At a Halloween event recently, my daughter and I walked past a free book table, and we are trying to find a book she saw but didn't grab based on the details she remembers:

The title is in gold letters
The bottom of the cover has gold leaves and vines
The background of the cover is red
In the foreground is a girl riding a broom stick.
The girl is wearing a blue dress and has blonde braids.
Around her are other children riding brooms.
None of the children have hats.
It is a chapter book.

It is not The Little Broomstick by Mary Stewart, no matter how many times ChatGPT insists that it is.
I worked with my daughter to come up with this MS paint illustration of the cover:

The black arrows are the other children also riding brooms. Alternatively, my daughter drew this herself:


Well, that's why we need Q&A sites with human experts rather than just asking ChatGPT :-)

@Randal'Thor I’m working with my daughter to come up with a “composite sketch” of the cover.

We have confirmed that it is The Daring of Della Dupree by Natasha Lowe:


Kudos to your daughter for her drawing skills! That was pretty darn accurate.
